# Can gravity be quantized in a way that doesn't require a particle?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, carrier-particles

I understand what gravitons are and why they are theorized to exist, but is there any way to quantize gravity without a boson? In other words, possibly geometrically with no particle at all?
For reference, I am a high school senior and have taken AP Physics 1&2, so I have a basic physics background.

Comment: The title asks if it can be done without a graviton, but the text asks whether it can be done without a boson. Are you asking whether it can be quantized without any force-carrying particle at all, or are you asking whether that particle has to be a boson rather than a fermion? It might help if you could edit the title and/or text appropriately.

Comment: *I understand what gravitons are and why they are theorized to exist* Maybe you could also flesh this out more. You're asking why they're expected to exist, and you say you know why they're expected to exist. What's your understanding of why they're expected to exist?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102794/2451 and links therein.